# Ngrx store Selector cannot access state

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am trying to select homeScore and awayScore from my MatchScoreboard object in MatchState

```
export const selectScoreboard = (state: MatchState) => state.scoreboard;

export const selectHomeScore = createSelector(selectScoreboard, (scoreboard) => scoreboard.homeScore);
export const selectAwayScore = createSelector(selectScoreboard, (scoreboard) => scoreboard.awayScore);
```

My state structure:

```
export interface MatchScoreboard {
    awayScore: number;
    homeScore: number;
}

export interface MatchState {
    scoreboard: MatchScoreboard;
}

export const initialState: MatchState = {
    scoreboard: {
        awayScore: 0,
        homeScore: 0,
    }
};
```

Selectors call

```
    store.pipe(select(selectHomeScore));
    store.pipe(select(selectAwayScore));
```

This appraoch works but it is not clean enough for me

```
    store.pipe(select('matchState', 'scoreboard', 'homeScore'));
    store.pipe(select('matchState', 'scoreboard', 'awayScore'));
```

When I try to use selectors I get errors that homeScore and awayScore are undefined in following lines of code

```
export const selectHomeScore = createSelector(selectScoreboard, (scoreboard) => scoreboard.homeScore);
export const selectAwayScore = createSelector(selectScoreboard, (scoreboard) => scoreboard.awayScore);
```

State is changed correctly everything is good except getting data through selectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you did with the string selector, you must first select `matchState` because `scoreboard` exists in `matchState`.

```
export const selectMatchState = (state: GlobalStatate) => state.matchState;
// or
export const selectMatchState = createFeatureSelector('matchState')
```

Now you can do:

```
export const selectScoreboard = createSelector(selectMatchState, selectScoreboard)

export const selectHomeScore = createSelector(selectScoreboard, (scoreboard) => scoreboard.homeScore);
export const selectAwayScore = createSelector(selectScoreboard, (scoreboard) => scoreboard.awayScore);
```

Comment: Ok it is good lead but what should be the type of generic in State class since it is State<T>

Comment: <GlobalState, FeatureState> https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/projects/example-app/src/app/books/reducers/index.ts#L54

Comment: There is no such type

Comment: I don't know your whole application, GlobalState was just a type I introduced - you don't have to provide I type if I remember correctly or just use `any`

Comment: Ok I get It. I am just wondering what is the state of global ngrx Store state. I mean the default state cause i can't find any info about it. Anyway thanks for help

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but you're building up the store state with your reducers. Maybe the docs can help you - https://ngrx.io/guide/store/reducers#defining-the-state-shape